# Integration of Docusign into web application

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to integrate Docusign API into my web application. I tried using Envelope Views where I am redirected to either login page or the signing page. But I would like to redirect to Add Recipients page from within my web application where the user can add the recipients, prepare the document and send it to the signer. Is there any method as such exposed from Docusign API?

Answer (score 0):

> Re: But I would like to redirect to Add Recipients page from within my web application where the user can add the recipients, prepare the document and send it to the signer.
>
> Is there any method as such exposed from DocuSign API?

Yes, the [EnvelopeViews::createSender](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender) view enables your application to open the Sender's view of the envelope on the DocuSign web site. The user can then add recipients, tabs, etc.

Here is a [code example](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-embedded-sending) that shows you how this works. You can download and run the code example in many languages.

### Information Security Notice

> This method, EnvelopeViews::createSender, provides full access to the sender's user account. When you use this view, the sender has full access to the user account. If the sender user account has administrative privileges, then this method also provides administrator access.
>
> If your use case needs to enable a sender to update a draft envelope before it is sent, then either:
>
> - Configure each sender to have their own individual user account to use this API method.
> - Enhance your API integration so that this method is not needed. Your integration can create the tabs, recipients and other envelope settings as needed.